# Condition to supress a field in crystal report

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I need a clarification how to suppress rest of field if another any one is satisfied(except the satisfied field others should be suppressed.

Actually the scenario is there is a field table called mode of transport and in that three field should be there

1. sea
2. ocean
3. air

If sea is selected inside that four field should be displayed

1. bill of lading
2. shipping number
3. destination
4. bill to

So for all the above three there are such sub fields

If one field for ex sea is selected the relevent above four filed related to sea as given should be displayed and rest of fields for air and road should be supressed.

Kindly anyone help me with the condition to solve it sooner.

Comment: . . I don't understand what your question is.  Perhaps sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Thank you peter.. Actually there are three fields i need rest of two should be supressed if one of three is satified.... If one field is applied the sub coulums should be displayed for it.Example-in mode of transport there are three fields road, ocean, air so after applying only one should be selected.... So kindly share the model condition applying to this scenario...as am new please explain me in detail

Answer (score 0):

In the suppress section of the field you want to suppress you can put a condition like that:

> {Command.MODE_OF_TRANSPORT} = 'sea'.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply..can u please explain me in detail aboit it... Because am new to crystal report

Comment: @Rajkumar When writing a formula for a suppress property of a field or section you use a logical statement that will evaluate to either true or false.  When the statement is true, the field or section will be suppressed, while false statements will not be suppressed.  The formula Stooge provided is equivalent to `If {Command.MODE_OF_TRANSPORT} = "sea" Then True Else False`.